# Bootstrap Navbar - Horizontal Push

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a site with Bootstrap. On a mobile device, I have a hamburger menu. This appears as part of the [Navbar](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/). When I click the navbar, the content of the page is pushed down and the menu appears at the top. This is the default behavior of Bootstrap's Navbar. I would like to push the content right and have my menu take up the full height of the device.

Is there a way to do this with Bootstrap? Currently, my code looks like this:

```
<div class="collapse" id="nav1">
  <h4>Hello</h4>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav1">
      &#9776;
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-8 center-block text-center">
    My App  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
    <button>login</button>                
  </div>
</nav>
```

Is there a way to make the hamburger menu appear along the side instead of the top?

Comment: checkout bigSlide: http://ascott1.github.io/bigSlide.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the jasny bootstrap - it's pretty nice and you can integrate it too bootstrap really easy without touching core files:

http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas

also, bootstrap already got a offcanvas function:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

Without testing:

```
<div class="sidebar-offcanvas" id="nav1">
  <h4>Hello</h4>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#nav1">
      &#9776;
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-8 center-block text-center">
    My App  
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
    <button>login</button>                
  </div>
</nav>
```

**////EDIT////**
Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chjdfqpg/2/